# I am considering upgrading to Kubuntu from Windows 10

Tags: sound, kubuntu, intel-graphics, huawei

However, these are my computer's specifications:
Windows 10 Home 64-bit
Intel Core i5 @ 1.60GHz
RAM: 16.0GB Dual-Channel DDR4 (17-17-17-39)
Graphics: BOE PnP Monitor (1920x1080@60Hz), Intel UHD Graphics (QUANTA Computer)
Audio: Realtek High Definition Audio

Yea, I'm using Huawei Matebook D15. I've seen a lot of threads saying that there are audio issues on this type of laptop, but they're from  a year or more ago. Users who have switched to Kubuntu or any Ubuntu distro similar, did you have issues with this? It's the only thing keeping me from switching to Linux.
I've used before the distro on my virtual machine and it was probably one of the most beautiful experiences I had with Linux since trying Ubuntu, Debian, Linux Mint and Kali.

So, what issues are you experiencing after swtiching from a huawei/huawei matebook D15 to this?
(Sorry for this mess of a comentary, it's my first time switching from Windows to Linux on my actual laptop. If I mess up a virtual machine, it's alright. But this?)

Comment: Run a live USB and try it.

Comment: I forgot about this post. I eventually did that, worked fine thank you!